# Calculate scene coordinates from QGraphicsLinearLayout

Tags: qt, coordinates, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, scene

In my application I used custom objects which derive from QGraphicsWidget and I put them inside QGraphicsLinearLayout. But now I need to find scene coordinates of each item. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsWidget` inherits from `QGraphicsObject` which in turn inherits from `QGraphicsItem`. So you can use one of the [`mapToScene`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToScene) function to convert item coordinates to the scene ones.

For example:

```
QPointF p = myItem->mapToScene(QPointF(0,0));
```

will give you the scene location of the top left corner of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#scenePos) from QGraphicsItem which is a base of QGraphicsWidget:

```
myItem->scenePos()
```